# PubNub history in Angular5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, pubnub

I am trying to post pubnub history to a web-app that I am building. I can only currently get it to the console. This is what I have :

```
pubnub.history(
    {
        channel: 'jChannel',

        reverse: false, // false is the default
        count: 100, // 100 is the default
        stringifiedTimeToken: true // false is the default
    },
    function (status, response)
    {
        // LOG HISTORY TO CONSOLE
        console.log("History Below: ")
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Does anyone know how I would then get this to post onto my web-app? 
I have tried doing:

```
{{response}}
```

Within my html, however this does not work. Any help appreciated.

my ts :

```
export class ArduinoAppComponent implements OnInit {
    public appStart = true;
    public myMessage;
    // CREATING MODEL FOR USER INPUT
    model = {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
    }
    constructor(pubnub: PubNubAngular) {
        // LINKJ TO PUBNUB
        pubnub.init({
            publishKey: 'pub-',
            subscribeKey: 'sub-'
        })
        pubnub.subscribe({
            channels: ['jChannel'],
            triggerEvents: true,
            withPresence: true,

        })
        // CREATE PUBNUB HISTORY
        pubnub.history(
            {
                channel: 'jChannel',
                reverse: false, // false is the default
                count: 100, // 100 is the default
                stringifiedTimeToken: true // false is the default
            },
            function (status, response) {
                // LOG HISTORY TO CONSOLE
                console.log("History Below: ")
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
```

and html:

```
<div class="col-md-3 minus-margin2">
    <h2 style="padding-top: 75%;"> What's next?</h2>
    <button class="btn btn-info">next?</button>
    {{response}}
</div>
```

Comment: can you post your html and the .ts class where you are using this?

Comment: @Overmachine done

Comment: This should be possible with proper binding in your Angular app. Have you reviewed everything here in the [PubNub Angular2 (should be compatible with Angular5) docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/angular2-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk)?

Comment: Someone from PubNub may post a more formal answer, but see these examples from our engineer: https://github.com/ManuelFernando/PubNub-Angular2-Demo-CLI

Answer (score 2):

you will need to store the value of the history response into a variable.

```
export class ArduinoAppComponent implements OnInit {
public appStart = true;
public myMessage;
public history: any = {};
// CREATING MODEL FOR USER INPUT
 model = {
   firstname: "",
   lastname:"",
}


constructor(pubnub: PubNubAngular) {
  // LINKJ TO PUBNUB
  pubnub.init({
      publishKey: 'pub-',
      subscribeKey: 'sub-'
      })
      pubnub.subscribe({
        channels: ['jChannel'],
        triggerEvents: true,
        withPresence: true,

    })

    // CREATE PUBNUB HISTORY
    pubnub.history(
    {
        channel: 'jChannel',

        reverse: false, // false is the default
        count: 100, // 100 is the default
        stringifiedTimeToken: true // false is the default
    }, function (status, response){
        //store response in variable defined above.
        this.history = response;
    }
);
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-3 minus-margin2">
 <h2 style="padding-top: 75%;"> What's next?</h2>
 <button class="btn btn-info">next?</button>
   <span>{{history}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'history' of object '[object Window]'

Comment: ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'history' of undefined

Comment: it seems that the response is an object you try getting the messages using response.messages and setting that to the history variable.
more here https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/api-reference-storage-and-playback#history

Comment: so when I do that I get the same error, but when i console.log(response) I get this:

Comment: {messages: Array(10), startTimeToken: "15238917484689756", endTimeToken: "15238917599944468"}